# Using Room in Android Library without referencing Room in the App

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-library

Does anyone know how to use Room in an Android Library without having to include any reference to Room in the Android (Java) app?

It's probably useful to note that I'm including a built `.aar` file of the Android Library in the `libs` folder which is then referenced by the `Android App application level build.gradle`. The Android Library and Android App have no connection to each other, other than through the compiled `.aar` file.

Here's what I'm basically doing:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MyCustomLibrary.storeSomething("The thing to store"); //method that calls Room stuff
}
```

The `storeSomething` method works as expected if I include Room in the app itself, and throws the following if I exclude it:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase;
```

My goal is to not have the app know anything about Room.

See below for all the `build.gradle` files.

#### Android Library project level `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### Android Library plugin level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'

}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
}
```

#### Android App project level `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### Android App application level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    //def room_version = "1.1.1" (it works if I include this line!)
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version" (it works if I include this line!)
    //annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version" (it works if I include this line!)
}
```

Comment: Looks like generated classes from **ROOM** are not included when you build **aar**.

Comment: @JeelVankhede How do I include the generated classes in my **.aar**?

Comment: Yes, thing is that for *app module*, **ROOM** is third party dependency from your library module and it can't resolve it directly. So, you'll have to add it manually in **build.gradle** of app otherwise it won't be able to find classes related to **ROOM** library.

Comment: Okay, I guess what I'm really asking for is to be able to have my library handle the storage of data, is **ROOM** not my best bet?

Comment: Nope, I think you're getting it wrong. **ROOM** is always best bet rather than general SQL. Thing is that when you import aar, it doesn't include ROOM library within it. For that purpose you'll need to make it **fat-aar** *(not recommended)* or else publish your library to any repo-server like Bintray.

Comment: Changing implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
  to api "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version" may solve your issue.

Comment: @JeelVankhede thanks for your feedback/help, I'll look into publishing my library to a repository and consume it that way instead of using a **fat-aar* plugin.

Comment: @Tshunglee I tried this and it still didn't work. I've also tried using the **fat-aar* method, but the process doesn't fit my use case.